# Highcharts drilldown with more than one series

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart where each yAxis value has two columns - this year and previous year. When a user drills down on one of the columns, it only drills down to the selected year. What I would like is to drill down for that yAxis on both last year and current year.

Here is an example chart: http://jsfiddle.net/w75oobt2/. If you click on A's Last Year, then it only shows a drilled down version for A's Last year. I would like it to show A's previous year as well.

Is this possible?

(Look at the B column - where the drill down has two series, but only shows the last one).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely it is not available,yet but you can post your suggestion in the uservoice service.

http://highcharts.uservoice.com